# kSoap and .Net webservice that returns a DataSet

Tags: java, blackberry, webservice-client, android-ksoap2

I know that using DataSets are a big evil, but as the service is not under my control and the prospect of creating a proxy service is a no go....

What i'm trying to see is if anyone has created class structure that can be deserialized using the kSoap serializer, or am i smoking the wrong stuff.

Going to start it in the mean time and see if it is possible.

Below is the resulting data as expected (Schema and Diffgram):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <SearchCustomerResponse xmlns="http://NCBI/WS/CRM">
      <SearchCustomerResult>
        <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
          <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Table">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="cussurKey" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="cusKey" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="FullName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="CIS" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="DCARKey" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="empBM" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="IDRegNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="RankCount" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="Source" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="GOICategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="cusperbanKey" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="GOIAmount" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
          <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
              <cussurKey>211806</cussurKey>
              <cusKey>0</cusKey>
              <FullName>*AMA WIESE H/A PLANTWISE SHADENET       </FullName>
              <CIS>191004669827</CIS>
              <DCARKey>3171</DCARKey>
              <empBM>0007974 - Scott, Sean John</empBM>
              <IDRegNo>0</IDRegNo>
              <RankCount>1</RankCount>
              <Source>Local</Source>
              <GOICategory>Zero</GOICategory>
              <cusperbanKey>7</cusperbanKey>
            </Table>
            <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
              <cussurKey>115457</cussurKey>
              <cusKey>0</cusKey>
              <FullName>*C H WIESE EN J A BAARD                 </FullName>
              <CIS>110587519304</CIS>
              <DCARKey>33351</DCARKey>
              <empBM>0135570 - Kriel, Werner</empBM>
              <IDRegNo>0</IDRegNo>
              <RankCount>2</RankCount>
              <Source>Local</Source>
              <GOICategory>Zero</GOICategory>
              <cusperbanKey>7</cusperbanKey>
            </Table>
          </NewDataSet>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
      </SearchCustomerResult>
    </SearchCustomerResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dataset is treated like an array of objects, as far as I can see, so you might want to consider a tutorial on how to return arrays of complex objects with KSOAP . You might need to create a Table class in Android and implement the KVMSerializable interface.

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html